# jQuery Mobile and Google Rich Snippets (SEO)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, seo, structured-data, google-rich-snippets

I have been thinking about using jQuery Mobile for a website of mine, but the fact that jQuery Mobile hijacks #fragment parts of links (e.g. mypage.html#fragment) means that you cannot deep link into a jQuery Mobile page.

That behaviour conflicts with the structured data / rich snippets of Google SEO, where you can tell Google via internal links which "sections" you have on your page. Then Google can link directly to a section from it's search results.

Does anyone know how to get around this? How to get deep links to work when referred by Google?